# Combining conways code with the gui

Tags: java, swing, user-interface

```
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
             grid=new JButton[length+20][width+20];
             grid1=new JButton[length+20][width+20];

            for(int i=0;i<length+2;i++)
            {
                for(int j=0;j<width+2;j++)
                {
                    grid1[i][j]=grid[i][j];
                }
            }


            for(int i=1;i<length+1;i++)
            {
                for(int j=1;j<width+1;j++)
                {
                    //final int row = i;
                    //final int col = j;

                    int count=0;

                    if(grid[i][j-1].getBackground() == Color.BLACK);
                        count++;

                    if(grid[i][j+1].getBackground()==Color.BLACK)
                        count++;

                    if(grid[i-1][j-1].getBackground()==Color.BLACK)
                        count++;

                    if(grid[i-1][j].getBackground()==Color.BLACK)
                        count++;

                    if(grid[i-1][j+1].getBackground()==Color.BLACK)
                        count++;

                    if(grid[i+1][j-1].getBackground()==Color.BLACK)
                        count++;

                    if(grid[i+1][j].getBackground()==Color.BLACK)
                        count++;


                    if(grid[i+1][j+1].getBackground()==Color.BLACK)
                        count++;

                    if(count==3)                    // exactly three neighbors
                    {

                        if(grid[i][j].getBackground()==Color.WHITE)
                        {
                            grid1[i][j].setBackground(Color.BLACK);         // birth cell
                        }
                    }

                    if(count==2 || count==3)            // 2 or 3 neighbors
                    {

                        if(grid[i][j].getBackground()==Color.BLACK)
                        {
                            grid1[i][j].setBackground(Color.BLACK);         // survives
                        }
                    }

                    if(count>=4 || count<=1)            //4 or more neighbors, or 1 or less neighbor
                    {
                        if(grid[i][j].getBackground()==Color.BLACK)
                        {
                            grid1[i][j].setBackground(Color.WHITE);         // dies from over-population or isolation
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

            for(int i=0;i<length+2;i++)
            {
                for(int j=0;j<width+2;j++)
                {
                    grid[i][j]=grid1[i][j];
                }
            }

            for(int i=1;i<length+1;i++)
            {
                for(int j=1;j<width+1;j++)
                {
                    System.out.print(grid[i][j]);
                }
                System.out.println("\n");
            }
        }
```

I am getting a nullpointer exception when I try to display the next generation of conway game of life using a GUI. Please suggest whats wrong with my code. The action performed method is executed when a start button is clicked

Comment: NullPointerException at which line?

Comment: Please share exception trace.

Comment: 1) For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/). 2) Always copy/paste error & exception output.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The cause of the NullPointerException is this:

```
grid  = new JButton[length+20][width+20];
grid1 = new JButton[length+20][width+20];
```

This way, you have a 2D-array of `JButtons`, but it is still full of `null` values. You have to initialize the individual "cells" in the array:

```
for (int i = 0; i < length+20; i++) {
    for(int j = 0; j < width+20; j++) {
        grid1[i][j] = new JButton();
    }
}
```

Also, is the size of the array intentional, or should it be `length+2` x `width+2` instead, as in your for-loop?

But this is not your actual problem: You create a new buttons-array, and then check the background colors of those newly created buttons. Assuming that `grid` represents the current state of the game, you are *erasing* the game state before doing the update. More likely, you have to drop the line `grid  = new JButton[length+20][width+20];` entirely.

And even this will not work correctly, as the two arrays `grid` and `grid1` will hold *the same* buttons, so when you change the background color of one, you also change the background color in the backup. With `grid1[i][j]=grid[i][j]` you just copy the reference to the button to the other array, but do not create a new button. And even if you did, you would have the problem that that new button would not be in the GUI at all.

Instead of storing your game state in the GUI elements, you should rather use two 2D-arrays of booleans (one for the current state, one as backup of the previous state during the state update) and set the background color of the buttons based on those booleans.